# Can not round corners of drawable with method setCornerRadius

Tags: android

I have simple `TextView`. I want set simple colored background with round corners.

I try two ways.

```
public static Drawable createRoundDrawable(int color, float radius) {
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setColor(color);
        drawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
        return drawable;
    }
```

And

```
public static Drawable createRoundDrawable(int color, float radius) {
        PaintDrawable drawable = new PaintDrawable(color);
        drawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
        return drawable;
    }
```

I create drawable with `createRoundDrawable` method and set background to textView by

```
textView.setBackground(background);
```

So, background applied to textView, but corners have no any radius. Why? And how to fix it?

Comment: I tried your code in my example project. It works for me. Can you share another information to us, for example your xml file, which api used etc.

Answer (score 0):

Better use a drawable XML file with rounded corner like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <!-- you can use any color you want-->
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Then set the file as drawable

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
```

it should be

```
   public static Drawable createRoundDrawable(int color, float radius) {
    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
    drawable.setColor(color);
    drawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
    return drawable;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
create a new Drawable resource file in drawable folder give it a name say custom_background.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

give radius and color of your choice and in layout file of textview add background tag
android:background="@drawable/custom_background"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting corner to individual corner with `setCornerRadii()`

```
public static Drawable createRoundDrawable(int color, float radius) {
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setColor(color);
        drawable.setCornerRadii(new float[] { radius, radius, radius, radius, radius, radius, radius, radius});
        return drawable;
    }
```